# Cannot access to port 80 on Google Cloud VM instance

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have setup Django in Linux Ubunut on GCE and run using :

```
sudo -E home/us1/python/bin/python  /home/us1/project/manage.py   runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

Server is started but when using my browser on ip_adress:80, I got an error message that :

```
This site can’t be reached, Too long to respond.
```

1) I checked the firewall set, open 80 is open...

Am not sure how I can get access to this website ?

Comment: try to create new firewall rule for tcp:8080, or host your project with some server like nginx or apache. Got same problem in my case but it was for angular2 project for i served my project from http-server module.

Comment: How can I assign this firewall to this particular VM ?

Comment: Inside the cloud console instance details just enable "http" and then add rules in firewall for both 80 and 8080 (although 80 is enough). Then Wait 5 mins and try again.

Comment: @Tensor you can create and assign tag with the instance details page and then when create firewall just mention the tags inside that firewall form.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (in case other people) are in same:

1) Ping the IP with CMD bash to check how is Ping.
2) Use Firefox which returns the HTTP error message
  (chrome doesn't in normal mode).